# Implementing QOpenGLWidget in Qt5

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

I am attempting to implement a QOpenGLWidget class using Qt Creator 4.0.2 on Qt 5.7.0 utilizing a programmable pipeline but I am unable to display a basic render.  I have been able to render in the past using fixed-function pipeline with glBegin/End but the programmable pipeline is not working.  The goal with this code is to display a non-shaded triangle (i havent developed the shader files yet) within the QOpenGLWidget which I promoted to my DrawingWidget class.  With the code below, I render the following output in Qt:
[image: OpenGLWidget Output]

if I add, glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); I get a red window, so the context and promoted class widget appears to be working, just does not render any of the given vertices.

**project1.pro**

```
QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    drawingwidget.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    drawingwidget.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

**DrawingWidget.h**

```
#ifndef DRAWINGWIDGET_H
#define DRAWINGWIDGET_H

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLExtraFunctions>

class DrawingWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, public QOpenGLExtraFunctions
{

Q_OBJECT

public:
    DrawingWidget(QWidget *parent);

protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();

private:
    GLuint m_vao;

private slots:


};

#endif // DRAWINGWIDGET_H
```

**drawingWidget.cpp**

```
#include "drawingwidget.h"
#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QOpenGLExtraFunctions>

DrawingWidget::DrawingWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

}

void DrawingWidget::initializeGL(){
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    GLfloat verts[] = {0.0f, 0.75f, 0.75f, -0.75f, -0.75f, -0.75f};
    GLuint vertexBufferID;
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void DrawingWidget::paintGL(){
    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>769</width>
    <height>518</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="DrawingWidget" name="openGLWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>300</width>
      <height>200</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>769</width>
     <height>19</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>DrawingWidget</class>
   <extends>QOpenGLWidget</extends>
   <header>drawingwidget.h</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "utilizing a programmable pipeline" where are your shaders then?

Comment: This is just to test that the current environment will render using a programmable pipeline.  Am I wrong in thinking that OpenGL should render a white (unshaded) object with this code that doesnt contain shaders?

Comment: Could just try Qt's OpenGL example projects and modify them? For example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-widgets-opengl.html.

Comment: I started out developing this using the widgets example but didnt reference back after I got into the opengl specific code.  Looks like there is some Qt specific code mentioned specifically how VAOs are handled. thanks.

Comment: You must provide at least a vertex shader. Not providing a fragment shader results in undefined output color but is valid.